# int obect not callable when calling len()

Tags: python, string, function, string-length

I'm simply trying to get the length of a string but the len() function is not working properly. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem here? I am using Jupyter Notebook. The code and the error are given below:

```
a = "heyyy"    
print(type(a))    
print(len(a))
```

[image]

Comment: You've created a numpy array (or whatever a `numpy.int64` is) called `len` somewhere.

Comment: You named a `numpy.int64` variable `len`.

Comment: Also, do not include screenshots of code or error messages in your questions.

Comment: Hint: examine what you did already (check out the previous 18 entries in your session). If worse comes to worst, just kill the session and start again.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You probably just assigned to built-in function `len` to an integer. Restart your kernel.